# Using Select to obtain certain elements

Tags: filtering

I want to do an apparently simple Select, tried all sorts of variations, but didn't find the correct. What I want is

```
tl = {{3, 2, .1}, {1, 4, .1}, {5, 3, .1}, {7, 6, .1}};

Select[tl, Unequal @@ {#[[1]], 3, 7} &]
```

only that the numbers 3 and 7 will change and also there might in some instances be more or less numbers. So what I really want is

```
l={3,7}
Select[tl, Unequal @@ {#[[1]], l} &]
```

which does not work. As said, it should be possible to have different numbers in l, and also the Length of l will change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l = {3, 7};
Select[tl, ! MatchQ @@ {#[[1]], Alternatives @@ l} &]
Select[tl, FreeQ @@ {#[[1]], Alternatives @@ l} &]
Select[tl, ! MemberQ[l, #[[1]]] &]
```

all give

```
(* {{1, 4, 0.1}, {5, 3, 0.1}} *)
```

If you have to use `Unequal`, here is a way:

```
Select[tl, And @@ Function[{x}, Unequal @@ {#[[1]], x}] /@ l &]
(* {{1, 4, 0.1}, {5, 3, 0.1}} *)
```

Also

```
Cases[tl, {Except[Alternatives @@ l], __}]
DeleteCases[tl, {Alternatives @@ l, __}]
Pick[tl, FreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ l] & /@ First /@ tl]
```

Comment: I heard somewhere that one could also use `DeleteCases`... (+1)

Comment: @Jens sounds familiar:)

Comment: Great, thanks. Yeah, maybe DeleteCases, I'll check it. However, as it is with a nested list, is possibly not simpler.

Comment: Instead of `Alternatives` I expect that `Or` but it doesn't. Do you know why?